# Ubuntu server No internet connection

Tags: networking, server, internet, netplan

Help me please. 3-rd day trying.

After installing ubuntu server there is no internet connection.
ipconfig not installed
and no possibility to install it because of internet connection

So. there is 3 interfaces (picture)
[image]
I`m trying to config netplan

```
network:
  ethernets:
    enp3s0:
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp6: true
    enp5s0:
      dhcp4: true
  version: 2
```

But there is no still internet.
I tried many options from the Internet, but apparently I don't understand something, please tell me smart people.

sudo lshw -C network
[image]

ls -al /etc/netplan

[image]

Comment: @guiverc Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS (Focal Fossa)

Comment: Edit your question and show me `sudo lshw -C network` and `ls -al /etc/netplan`. Describe your ethernet cabling from the computer to the router/modem. What is connected to each ethernet port? Are the ethernet ports discrete cards?

Comment: @heynnema can i possibly edit my question? I`m trying to reinstall ubuntu, and while installing i see this. https://paste.pics/DW9QB Can u possibly help me pleeeease?

Comment: Answer my questions and I'll try to help. Click the [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1364199/edit) link under your question, to edit your question.

Comment: Is the invalid MAC address for enp3s0 something of your doing?

Comment: @heynnema i added. Look at please. Yes, but i reinstall ubuntu server again.

Comment: You didn't answer all of my questions. Please pay attention. Thanks.

Comment: @heynnema Well, I don't even know how to describe ethernet cabling to you. A regular Internet cable goes to the router. There are 3 cables coming out of the router. And I installed ubuntu on one server and everything is ok, but with the second a similar thing.

Comment: Are you using cat 5e or cat 6 cables? Does the ethernet cable go DIRECTLY from the computer RJ45 port to the router? Are there two similar servers involved... one works and the other has this problem? Have you rebooted the router? What brand router?

Comment: @heynnema 1. Don`t know actually how to get this information. 2. Yes. 3. Yes 4. Yes tried several times. 5. Provider router his named

Comment: The ethernet cable would say cat 5e or cat 6 on the cable jacket. Is the ethernet cable connected to a LAN port on the router? Are both etherport ports on the server being used? I'll be back later... I have to cook dinner.

Comment: Do you have the admin password for the router? For the server that works, what LAN port is it plugged into the router? For the server that does not work, what LAN port is it plugged into the router?